# Grep in R using AND

Tags: regex, r

Is there a way to pass two terms to grep for search for?

Imagine I wanted to find items in an object containing both "five" and "six" i.e "five" AND "six" .

```
grep("five" & "six", object)
```

This will not work, I know there is notation for OR with |.

Comment: you could write two `intersect(grep('five', object), grep('six', object))`

Comment: IMO, it's pretty simple to just do `grep('five.*six|six.*five', object)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lookahead is not **needed** to do this, you can use the [**alternation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator in context.

```
grep('five.*six|six.*five', object)
```

If you know that "five" will precede "six" on the line, you don't even need the alternatives:

```
grep('five.*six', object)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `grepl` to figure out which elements meet both criteria and then index those out.

```
id <- grepl("five", object) & grepl("six", object)
object[id]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion based regex. Since lookarounds are PCRE feature, you must need to set `perl=TRUE`.

```
grep("^(?=.*five)(?=.*six)", object, perl=TRUE)
```

**OR**

```
grep("^(?=.*\\bfive\\b)(?=.*\\bsix\\b)", object, perl=TRUE)
```

**OR**

```
grep("^(?=.*\\bfive\\b).*\\bsix\\b", object, perl=TRUE)
```

**Example:**

```
> x <- c("five six bar", "five", "six")
> grep("^(?=.*\\bfive\\b)(?=.*\\bsix\\b)", x, perl=TRUE) 
[1] 1
```

Comment: Actually, lookarounds are not needed at all.

Comment: There is no need to use alternation operator, a single lookahead would be fine. Seems like a vice-versa :-)